# authentication between mainframe system and .net web service

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ssl-certificate, mainframe, client-certificates

We have a .net web service that talks to a mainframe system. We would like to introduce some security mechanism to this. What are the different options available? Whether using client certificate will help in this case?

Comment: What mainframe system are you communicating with?  CICS? IMS?

Comment: Talk to the Mainframe security people at your site. You'd do best to assume that the data on the Mainframe is more secure than you thought possible, rather than "how do we introduce security", otherwise they'll have a hard time taking you seriously.

Comment: We finally agreed to go with client certificate.